# C# Using ReadProcessMemory to Search Memory and Provide Address of Found Array

Tags: c#, arrays, memory

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;


namespace BaseAddress
{
    class Program`enter code here`
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(int hProcess, Int64 lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer,
                                 int nSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesWritten);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(int hProcess,
            Int64 lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, ref int lpNumberOfBytesRead);
        const int PROCESS_WM_ALL = 0xFFFF;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
            Console.WriteLine(GetBase("Notepad"));
            Console.WriteLine(GetAdd("Notepad",FromHex("59-00-6F-00-59-00"));
 }


    public static long  GetAdd(string app, byte[] findthis)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[findthis.Length];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        long foundAddr = 0;
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(app);
        Process process = processes[0];
        IntPtr procHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_ALL, false, process.Id);
        long addr = 13188986418;
        Console.WriteLine(addr);
        Console.WriteLine("Starting address 0x{0}", (addr).ToString("X"));
        bool ret2 = ReadProcessMemory((int)procHandle, addr, buffer, buffer.Length, ref bytesRead);
        string p = BitConverter.ToString(buffer,0);
        string tmp = BitConverter.ToString(findthis, 0);
        Console.WriteLine(p);
        Console.WriteLine(tmp);
        if (p == tmp)
        {
            foundAddr = addr;
            Console.WriteLine("Found it at 0x{0}", foundAddr.ToString("X"));
        } else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NO");
        }
        return foundAddr;
    }


    static long GetBase(string app)
    {
        long add = 0;
        using (Process proc = new Process())
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(app);
            ProcessModule pm;
            ProcessModuleCollection pmc = processes[0].Modules;
            for (int i = 0; i < pmc.Count; i++)
            {
                pm = pmc[i];
                if(pm.ModuleName.Replace(".exe","") == processes[0].ProcessName)
                {
                    add = pm.BaseAddress.ToInt64();
                }
            }
        }
        return add;
    }

    public static byte[] FromHex(string hex)
    {
        hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
        byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
        {
            raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }
        return raw;
    }
```

So what I'm trying to do is create a function that I can provide the process name ("Notepad" in this example) and a byte array (in hex) and then the program scans the process in memory, finds the first instance of the matching array, and provides the address of it.

This works for finding a byte array BUT i have to hard code the starting point
what i don't understand is how the base address is 140696861212672 (dec)
yet the address where the code actually is is 13188986418 (dec)

This is the console output:

```
140696861212672
13188986418
Starting address 0x3121FF632
59-00-6F-00-59-00
59-00-6F-00-59-00
Found it at 0x3121FF632
13188986418
```

Any idea how i can get this to start at the start of the memory, skip empty zones in memory and loop a chunk of byte array until the array is found?

Hope that makes sense.  Any help is welcome.

Comment: dumb question - where did that literal 131889.... come from? How do you know its correct

Comment: I mean you dont even test to see if ReadProcessMemory worked in GetAdd, I bet it didnt